# Nuxt 2 - SSG - Embed data in HTML

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, static-site-generation, nuxtjs2

I saw that Nuxt 2 stores data in json files called `payload.js` in SSG mode.

Instead to store these data in json files, is it possible to store the data directly in HTML files, after the generation ?

Thanks

[image: All payloads.js files]

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. What would be the use-case for such thing? Otherwise, you could give a try to [AstroJS](https://astro.build/) or even [îles](https://github.com/ElMassimo/iles).

Comment: @kissu just have less requests

Comment: That have nothing to do with JSON so. Did you read that one? https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/

Comment: I red it in the main documentation. What is a shame is that on our Blog home page, we will have 20-30 requests just for payload.js files. Each one corresponds to articles, pages, categories, tags etc... is there a way to optimize it ?

Comment: Those are local requests, so nothing with an issue regarding network latency. Then, you also have those requests because of prefetch, that you can download if you want. Even tho, it's made for a faster client-side navigation after the initial render. So basically, it's already optimized by default but you can opt out of specific features if you want.

Comment: I am not so sure, there still a "waiting" time for each file (as you can see in screenshot above). About 200ms for each one. If you multiply it for every ressources, it starts to cost.

Comment: Do you have a public URL for that one? Can you try disabling the prefetching? The redline is when the whole thing is done blocking the thread if I'm not mistaken. Not sure if prefetch is blocking at initial render.

Comment: Yes, I would loved to share you, but can't to expose the url publically. I will send you by email I found on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an offline discussion, I've concluded that OP's main issue was more of a heavy image usage (≈40MB of `.png`) + other basics Web Core Vitals to get fixed rather than some prefetched pages set by Nuxt.

[image]

I've also provided the following links to improve the overall performance of their SSG app:

- https://web.dev/learn/
- https://www.patterns.dev/posts/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/01/front-end-performance-2021-free-pdf-checklist/

The goal being to do 20% of the heavy work for 80% of no-comprise better metrics. The rest being more advanced/subject to internal discussions as of how to proceed regarding the respective drawbacks.